# UICollectionView reuse cell issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a problem with collection view cell. When my collection view first loaded, it display items like that:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{


    CalendarCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CalendarCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell bindDate:_datesMgr.currentMonthItems[indexPath.row] andNowDate:_datesMgr.nowDate];


    // bind events

    if (_eventsMgr.eventsArray.count > 0){

        for (int i = 0; i < _eventsMgr.eventsArray.count ; i ++) {
            [cell bindConference:_eventsMgr.eventsArray[i]];
        }
    }


    return cell;
}
```

Inside those methods are logic for adding subviews to custom cell class, which depend on certain circumstances.

Its all work, but, when collection view reloaded (i did force reload after 1 second) some of cells are reused and placed on others, therefore, it show "old" images and subviews.

I could see possible solution in forcing uicollection view to stop reusing cells (it is, load new cells every time). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `adding subviews to custom cell` this means are you creating new instances of subviews and adding in code? If yes, you need to remove the old subviews if exist.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr how exactly should i do that, and find occasion where i need to delete them?

Comment: either you can add each subview a specific tag and remove the view by using corresponding tag, or you can remove all subviews from particular view and add them again. Since you are using custom cells, I prefer to design the cell in xib or storyboard and use outlets to set values to each instead of creating new instance and adding each time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to implement `prepareForReuse` method for reset your old content in your custom `UICollectionViewCell`

```
-(void)prepareForReuse {
   [super prepareForReuse];
   self.yourimageview.image = nil; //and etc.
}
```

Comment: and if there is a correct cell (which correct image) and i set image to nil?

Comment: If you set the image to nil (actually you should remove any subviews that were added) then the image will be reset (or the subviews re-added) in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: For all images set to nil and when will reload your cells set again data by indexPath

Comment: but if implemented like this, there is a flickering; why are the cells reused for the wrong indexPath in the first place?